# Extending Mel Spectrogram example from Apple Developers' docs to the case of recorded samples instead of live microphone

Tags: swift, signal-processing, linear-algebra, cblas

I'm building on top of Apple Developer's documentation example called [Computing the Mel Spectrum Using Linear Algebra](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/computing_the_mel_spectrum_using_linear_algebra). My goal is to extend this example in order to be able to apply it to samples recorded from live microphone. Specifically I use the subroutine from this example the following way:

```
while(i*hopCnt + windowSize < samples.count) {
        
    if i*hopCnt + windowSize > samples.count {
        samplesInThisWindow = Array(samples[i*hopCnt+windowSize..<samples.count])
        samplesInThisWindow.append(
                contentsOf: [Float].init(repeating: 0, count: i*hopCnt+windowSize - samples.count)
        )
     } else {
        samplesInThisWindow = Array(samples[i*hopCnt..<i*hopCnt+windowSize])
     }
                
     let FFTValues = subroutineFromExample(samplesInThisWindow: &samplesInThisWindow)
     stftSpectrogram.append(contentOf: FFTValues)
}

return stftSpectrogram
```

When this routine is completed I get back as a result the STFT transform of the samples and the Mel spectrogram has yet to be computed. This means that FFT is a (time_bins x window_size) matrix where time_bins = (samples_count - window_size)/hop_size + 1.

At this point I'm back at computing the Mel spectrogram using the code in the example, which produces a MEL `filterBanks` matrix that is a (filterbanks_count x window_size) matrix (Not sure, I guess so since the `makeFilterBank` method contains the following code: `row = i * window_size`). Then the code proceeds with the following code to compute the spectrogram through matrix multiply:

```
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor,
            CblasTrans,
            CblasTrans,
            Int32(1),
            Int32(self.filterbanksCount),
            Int32(self.windowSize),
            1,
            fftResultPtr.baseAddress,
            Int32(1),
            filterBank.baseAddress,
            Int32(self.windowSize),
            0,                
            sgemmResult!.baseAddress,
            Int32(self.filterbanksCount)
        )
```

So, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1513264-cblas_sgemm?language=objc), this either computes C←αAB + βC or C←αBA + βC where A and B can optionally be transposed.

The code from the examples expects to receive a (1 x window_size) matrix as result of FFT because it processes a single time bin at a time, therefore in this case FFT is (1 x window_size), MEL `filterBanks` is (filterbanks_count x window_size). Since `CblasTrans` is specified for both the input matrices and neither A^tB^t nor B^tA^t would be of the right dimensions for a product, I'll assume that MEL `filterBanks` is actually (window_size x filterbanks_count), which means that `sgemmResult = MEL^t*FFT^t` and `cblas_sgemm` is operating in C←αBA + βC mode.

This entails that sgemmResult is a (filterbanks_count x 1) matrix.

Now this is a bit of a pain in the back for me to generalize because my interface expects to receive as an input the rotated spectrogram, that is, a (time_bins x window_size) matrix while the obvious generalization would be to replace all the hardcoded `1`s in the code with `FFT.count/window_size` (FFT is represented in [row-major order](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Row_and_column_major_order.svg/1200px-Row_and_column_major_order.svg.png)).

Doing so would produces as an output a (filterbanks_count x time_bins) matrix and as a result, the rendered spectrogram looks funny (looks like multiple frequency bins are combined horizontally to fill the available width, as I'd expect anyway). So my idea was the following: Instead of computing `MEL(FFT) = MEL^t*FFT^t` I'd compute `MEL(FFT)^t = FFT*MEL` and get the correct result.

[image: Illustration of the reasoning from Apple Documentation here]

(Note that Apple's Developers code uses `windowSize` as the parameter for number of rows of B matrix (`filterBank` in the code), therefore `filterBank` matrix is just about the Filter bank (trasposed) represented in the above image)

This produces the following code:

```
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor,  //ORDER
                    CblasNoTrans,     //Transpose A? if so, op(A) = A^t, else op(A) = A
                    CblasNoTrans,     //Transpose B? if so, op(B) = B^t, else op(B) = B
                    Int32(fftResult.count/self.windowSize), //A and C's rows.
                    Int32(self.filterbanksCount),   //B and C's cols.
                    Int32(self.windowSize), //A's cols, B's rows
                    1,  //Scale A and B's product
                    fftResultPtr.baseAddress,   //A
                    Int32(self.windowSize), //rows of op(A)^t
                    filterBank.baseAddress, //B
                    Int32(self.filterbanksCount), //rows of op(B)^t
                    0,  //Result scale
                    sgemmResult!.baseAddress,   //C
                    Int32(self.filterbanksCount)    //rows of C^t
            )
```

So, if I use the above code in place of the existing one, as a result I get a spectrogram where the lower frequencies take about 20% of the overall height while the higher frequencies take the remaining 80%, which means that the hypothetical effect of applying the Mel scale to the linear spectrogram is flipped.

Where did my reasoning fail, and how should I go about fixing my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that according to the image in the post, the STFT result, that is (time_bins x window_size), must not be transposed. This observation eventually led me to the correct solution, that is the following:

```
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor,  //ORDER
            CblasNoTrans,     //Transpose A?
            CblasTrans,     //Transpose B?
            Int32(fftResult.count/self.windowSize), //A and C's rows.
            Int32(self.filterbanksCount),   //B and C's cols.
            Int32(self.windowSize), //A's cols, B's rows
            1,  //Scale A and B's product
            fftResultPtr.baseAddress,   //A
            Int32(self.windowSize), //rows of op(A)^t
            filterBank.baseAddress, //B
            Int32(self.windowSize), //rows of op(B)^t
            0,  //Result scale
            sgemmResult!.baseAddress,   //C
            Int32(self.filterbanksCount)    //rows of C^t
    )
```

Where `fftResult.count/self.windowSize` returns the amount of time bins in the STFT since the STFT matrix is what's called `fftResult` in the above code